# Liferay: Removing /web/ from all community sites

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, liferay, virtualhost, liferay-6

I can't seem to figure out how to do a url rewrite so that I can remove the /web/ from all of my community sites:

```
domain.com/web/communitysite1/page
domain.com/web/communitysite2/page
domain.com/web/communitysite3/page
domain.com/web/communitysite4/page
```

and I want it to be,

```
domain.com/communitysite1/page
domain.com/communitysite2/page
domain.com/communitysite3/page
domain.com/communitysite4/page
```

Here's a [thread](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/447746) from Liferay, the solution there is using the virtual host; however, that's only for one of the community site for that one domain but I need the domain to be all the same for all the community sites I'm doing.

Comment: Oops, I forgot the thread url on liferay; http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/447746

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Yazmat for your kind help.
@Prakash K Here's what I am currently using, it's a different solution using proxy mod.

`ProxyHTMLExtended On
ProxyHTMLEnable On
SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
ProxyHTMLURLMap ^/web/(.*)$ /$1 Rli`

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to manualy change your pages links from domain.com/web/community... to domain.com/community

After that you need a rewrite rule to rewrite the new url to the old one without notifying users :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^web/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then you will need a rule to redirect users that still access the old url to the new one while changing their browser link :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^web/
RewriteRule ^web/(.*)$ /$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Then you need to mix that up, **BUT**, if you do, you will get an infinite loop, so you need something to avoid that (a trick I use is to add an optional parameter to the first rule and check in the second one if it exists or not, if it do then you don't redirect) :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^web/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(.*&)?r=0(&.*)?$
RewriteRule ^web/(.*)$ /$1 [L,QSA,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^web/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1?r=0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: what do you mean in the first part... manually changing my page links? I am assuming, but I think I am wrong with this assumption, you mean to change the friendly url of each of the pages within the community site? Or do you mean to create the pages within the main domain's site pages reflecting those in the community site pages?

btw, I really appreciate your response. thank you!

Comment: What I mean is, for example you have a page home.html that contains a link like : `<a href="/web/communitysite1/page">link</a>` , you need to change it to `<a href="/communitysite1/page">link</a>` (that's what I ment)

Comment: Oh okay, thanks.
I'm configuring this in my vhost file and this
`RewriteBase /` is breaking my apache...

Comment: that is weird, I edited my answer (removed the rewritebase but also added a '/' in the rewriteRules )

Comment: I'm getting 404 pages for everything now; is there a place that I can show you my vhost configuration? I think it's causing some rewrite issues.

Comment: @Seed does this really answer your question?